# Setting up ActorSystem Akka (Scala)

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

I am trying to create a fibonacci actor that will calculate fibonacci(n) by creating other actors (for learning purposes) so far I am trying to set up a simple actor and ActorSystem as such:

```
import FibActor1.fib
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.Logging


  class FibActor1 extends Actor {
    val res = 0
    val log = Logging(context.system, this)

    def receive = {
      case fib(n)
      => fib(n) match {
        case fib(0) =>
          sender ! res
        case fib(1) =>
          sender ! res + 1
//        case fib(x) => TODO
      }
        context.stop(self)
    }
  }

object FibActor1 { // companion object
  case class fib(n: Int)
  case class result(n: Int, actorRef: ActorRef)

}

object ActorMain extends App {
    lazy val oursystem = ActorSystem("ExampleSystem")
    val fibActor = oursystem.actorOf(Props[FibActor1], "fibActor")
    fibActor ! fib(0) // Testing the base case
}
```

However when I run ActorMain, I get this error and I'm having a hard time figure out why (apologies for the long error message):

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50796:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/Kareem/CMPT340/ScalaWork/out/production/Assignment4:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor-typed_2.13/2.6.1/akka-actor-typed_2.13-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.13/2.6.1/akka-actor_2.13-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.13/2.6.1/akka-slf4j_2.13-2.6.1.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.4.0/config-1.4.0.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-java8-compat_2.13/0.9.0/scala-java8-compat_2.13-0.9.0.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.1/scala-library-2.13.1.jar:/Users/Kareem/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.29/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar:/Users/Kareem/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/Users/Kareem/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.10.jar ActorMain
22:33:01.840 [ExampleSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
Uncaught error from thread [ExampleSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(Lscala/concurrent/BatchingExecutor;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ExampleSystem]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(Lscala/concurrent/BatchingExecutor;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:873)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:392)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:302)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:242)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:585)
    at akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Slf4jLogger.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:533)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:531)
    at akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.aroundReceive(Slf4jLogger.scala:55)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:573)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:543)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:269)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
[ERROR] [SECURITY][03/22/2020 22:33:01.867] [ExampleSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(ExampleSystem)] Uncaught error from thread [ExampleSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(Lscala/concurrent/BatchingExecutor;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ExampleSystem]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(Lscala/concurrent/BatchingExecutor;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:873)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:392)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:302)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:242)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:585)
    at akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Slf4jLogger.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:533)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:531)
    at akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger.aroundReceive(Slf4jLogger.scala:55)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:573)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:543)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:269)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I have a feeling it might be a slight issue but I don't know enough about akka actors to find out what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate any help.

Comment: My first guess: mismatched akka and scala version. What version of akka and scala are you using?

Comment: Yes, can be seen in the classpath on the first line, mixing Scala 2.13 and 2.12 artifacts. Scala is not binary compatible across versions like that so you need to align all libraries to be the same, preferrably 2.13